# Fonts in Assets Pipeline is not referred with fingerprint in the final CSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have been playing around with this deployment issues for a while now. Basically it seems like that the fonts files are passed into the `public/assets/` folder after the `assets:precompile` (I have deleted the whole `assets` folder and let Rails to recompile again). No matter what I have tried, the css still comes out with the path without fingerprint. Can anyone help to identify what's wrong with my code? I know I can do some monkey works to get around it by just copying the fonts to the `public/assets` but I think it is not a good practice in a long run.

Here's the setup:

Resulting Client-side CSS:- No fingerprint at all...

```
@font-face {
    font-family:cabinmedium;
    src:url(cabin-medium/cabin-medium-webfont.eot?#iefix) format(embedded-opentype),url(cabin-medium/cabin-medium-webfont.woff) format(woff),url(cabin-medium/cabin-medium-webfont.ttf) format(truetype),url(cabin-medium/cabin-medium-webfont.svg#cabinmedium) format(svg);
    font-weight:400;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

fonts.css.scss:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'cabinmedium';
    src: font-url('cabin-medium/cabin-medium-webfont.eot');
    src: font-url('cabin-medium/cabin-medium-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         font-url('cabin-medium/cabin-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         font-url('cabin-medium/cabin-medium-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         font-url('cabin-medium/cabin-medium-webfont.svg#cabinmedium') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

And of coz in the `production.rb`, I have added the fonts path in the assets path:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
```

In case it is of someone's interests, here is the `assets.rb` in the `config/initializers/` folder:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << Proc.new do |path|
    if path =~ /\.(css|js|coffee|scss)\z/
    full_path = Rails.application.assets.resolve(path).to_path
    app_assets_path = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets').to_path
    if full_path.starts_with? app_assets_path
      puts "including asset: " + full_path
      true
    else
      puts "excluding asset: " + full_path
      false
    end
  else
    false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have managed to track down the problem!

1. I need to explicitly declare using the assets pipeline in `production.rb`:

   config.assets.enable = true
2. Then, in the `assets.rb` in `initializers`, I include the fonts but do not include the `.coffee` and `.scss`

   ```
   Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << Proc.new do |path|

   if path =~ /\.(css|js|eot|svg|ttf|woff)\z/
    full_path = Rails.application.assets.resolve(path).to_path
    app_assets_path = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets').to_path
    if full_path.starts_with? app_assets_path
      puts "including asset: " + full_path
      true
    else
      puts "excluding asset: " + full_path
      false
    end       
   else
    false
    end
   end
   ```

The problem I had before is caused by two reason:

1. When I include .scss in assets precompile, there is some problem with the compilation of the scss. From Rails' documentation, it mentioned that scss and coffee do not need to be included because the compiled files (.css and .js) will be included. That may cause some problem with the `font-url`. The reason behind is unknown so if someone can explain that would be cool!
2. Need to include the fonts extensions: `eot|svg|ttf|woff` so that they are included in the pipeline.

I hope this would help someone.